# Understanding lexer rule resolution in ANTLR4

Tags: java, antlr4, lexer

I'm reading the ANTLR4 defenitive guide and now I'm at the section about lexer rule resolution. Here is what's written in this section:

```
grammar KeywordTest;
enumDef : 'enum' '{' ... '}';
...
FOR: 'for'
...
ID:[a-zA-Z]; // does not match 'enum' or 'for'
```

> Rule ID could also match kewords such as `enum` or `for`, which means
>   there's more than one rule that could match the same
>   string. [...] **Literals such as `'enum'` become lexical rules and go**
>   **immediately after the parser rules but before the explicit lexical**
>   **rules.**

What does it mean and how does it help us to resolve the potential ambiguities? I would say that a declaration like

```
ENUM_KEYWORD: 'enum'
```

which `ATNLR4` might use internally would be decalred right after the rule `enumDef: 'enum' '{' ... '}` and will look as follows:

```
enumDef: ENUM_KEYWORD '{' ... '}
ENUM_KEYWORD: 'enum'
```

Is that exactly how ANTLR4 does things?

Answer (score 1):

Order of lexer rules is very important in grammar, as the first applicable rule found will be used. You can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35580245/understanding-antlr4-tokens/35664385#35664385).

So if you have lexer rules:

```
ID: [a-zA-Z]+;
FOR: 'for';
```

based on its order input "for" will be marked as FOR token or as ID token, because for both it is correct.

As a result, grammars very often contains rule 'ambigous' where all keywords are mentioned so when another token contains keyword it would pass.

For example:

```
alfaNum: (ALFA | NUM | ambigous | '_' )+?;
ambigous: SELECT | WHERE | FROM | WITH | SET | AS;
```

this way if there is alfaNum token "selection", it would pass. If ambigous would not be specified, it would fail over lexer rule `SELECT: 'select';`